# Raising the content in brackets in math mode

Tags: math-mode, tabulary

@egreg helped me to get my math AVMs right ([Aligning math brackets in AVMs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295695/aligning-math-brackets-in-avms/295700#295700)). I noticed that it is more common to have the type at the top of the AVM and I changed the code to reflect this. However, I think that there is too much space now between the top of the AVM and the type information.

[image]

The types *word*, *local*, and *category* should be higher. Of course how much higher depends on the font. Is there a way to do this? The whole tabular content should be raised but without having additional space at the bottom due to this raising.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\newcommand{\ms}[2][]{%
  \mbox{%
    \delimiterfactor=1000 \delimitershortfall=0pt
    \tabcolsep=0pt
    $\left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\normalfont\itshape}l}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\normalfont\itshape}l}{#1}%
     \\ 
    \fi
    #2%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]$%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}

\def\ibox#1{\mbox{}\setbox2=\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\lower.2ex\vbox{\hrule
        \hbox{\vrule\kern1.25pt 
        \vbox{\kern1.25pt\box2\kern1.25pt}\kern1.25pt\vrule}\hrule}}

\newcommand{\liste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$%
\left\langle\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}\right\rangle%
$%
}%
}

\newcommand{\phonliste}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$%
%
\left\langle \mbox{\normalfont\itshape#1} \right\rangle%
$%
}%
}


\begin{document}

\ms[word]{
phonology   & \phonliste{ Grammatik } \\[1mm]
syntax-semantics & \ldots \ms[local]{ category  & \ms[category]{ head & \ms[noun]{ case & \ibox{1}
                                                                                               }\\[6mm]
                                                                               subcat & \liste{ Det[\textsc{case}~\ibox{1}] }
                                                                             } \\[6mm]
                                          content & \ldots \ms[grammatik]{ inst & X 
                                                                                    }
            }
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I would simply get rid of the `\extrarowheight`

Comment: Yes, but this affects also the space between lines in the table that do not contain type information. But I agree, it looks better than with this extra space. So I will correct things where there is too little space by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the extra height in the first row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\ms}[2][]{%
  \mbox{%
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}% we don't want it to affect every array, do we?
    \delimiterfactor=1000 \delimitershortfall=0pt
    \tabcolsep=0pt
    $\left[%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}>{\hspace*{5pt}\normalfont\itshape}l}
    \noalign{\vspace{-\extrarowheight}}
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\normalfont\itshape}l}{#1}%
     \\ 
    \fi
    #2%
    \end{tabular}%
    \right]$%
  }%
  \vspace{1mm}%
}

\newcommand{\ibox}[1]{{%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.25pt}%
  \fbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}\,%
}}

\newcommand{\liste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left\langle
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\upshape\scshape}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}
    \right\rangle
    $%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\phonliste}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    $%
    \left\langle
    \mbox{\normalfont\itshape#1}%
    \right\rangle
    $%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\ms[word]{
  phonology & \phonliste{ Grammatik } \\[1mm]
  syntax-semantics & \ldots
    \ms[local]{
      category &
        \ms[category]{
          head & \ms[noun]{ case & \ibox{1} }\\[6mm]
          subcat & \liste{ Det[\textsc{case}~\ibox{1}] }
        } \\[6mm]
      content & \ldots \ms[grammatik]{ inst & X }
    }
  }

\end{document}
```

[image]

The small differences are due to how TeX computes the size of the delimiters and there's no easy solution to this problem.

Note the changes in the definition of `\ms` in order to

1. Set `\extrarowheight` only locally
2. Get rid of the extra space in case there's only one column

I also reduced the definition of `\ibox` to human form. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks for `\ibox`. This is very old code that I took from the `avm` package ...